# How to call a solana program with multiple signers

Tags: rust, blockchain, solana

Let's say I have a program where I want the initialization call to be signed by multiple wallets. How to proceeds, I suppose I pass x accounts as signers, but in terme of UI/user interactions how does that play out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think this is the way. Indirection through a program that does the gathering of signs.

You init a multisig tx, set all the details and signers count.

Signers refer this calling the multisig program, effectively signing it

Once the treshold is reach, you call the execute ix of that multisig program, and it does a multisig CPI call.

https://github.com/project-serum/multisig/blob/master/programs/multisig/src/lib.rs

Answer (score 2):

You could use initiate a transaction from the client side and add signatures to it.
Check [this](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Transaction.html#addSignature)

`sign()`, `addSignature()`, `partialSign()` can be used to sign it with multiple accounts.

Comment: Thanks Aadhi, let me rephrase cause my question is not well formulated: How do you add signatures in a regular UI where only one wallet is connect, how to multisign in that case

Comment: Oh okay. I think you need to pass around the transaction after getting it signed from one. I'm not sure about this approach. If I figure it out I'll let you know.

Comment: I think I found the right way, please see the answer I submitted below

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Snowflake Safe and submit Solana generic multisig transactions either programatically using the SDK or via Snowflake Safe App.

SDK: https://github.com/snowflake-so/snowflake-safe-sdk
App: https://safe.snowflake.so